# How to synchronize ios device contact with qt app?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, qt

I want to sync up iOS device contacts with an application based on QT platform, I am in search of an API which can do this with qt

I find workaround (QT-JNI-Java bridge) for android.

[http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#details)

It is working fine, but i didn't find any bridge for ios.

**Note:** QT has suggested following link

https://wiki.qt.io/Category:Developing_with_Qt::QtMobility

But it is related to Nokia Ovi store (which doesn't exist anymore) and the last date mentioned is 2011. The link to a release is dead.

If you come across any workaround for ios-qt, request you to suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the V-Play API for a cross-platform solution to handle phone contacts on iOS & Android.

These are the APIs:

https://v-play.net/doc/nativeutils/#getContacts-method

https://v-play.net/doc/nativeutils/#storeContacts-method